# how can I pass a dictionary of items contianing dictionaries of items?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, datacontractserializer

I have a service that I am trying to pass a dictionary of objects through. All is well and works until I add a Dictionary of objects that then contains a Dictionary to yet another object. The dictionary causing the problem would be class A in the below example.

```
    //example

    public class A
    {
     public Dictionary<string,B> BValues { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
     public Dictionary<string, C> CValues { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
     int x;
     int y;
    }
```

I have tried making the the dictionaries knowntypes in my service, and also making sure the other classes are marked as a data contract, their properties marked with the DataMember attribute. I'm at a loss on what else I need to or even can do in order to make this work.

**Edit**

The exception:

> Element
>   'schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value';
>   contains data of the
>   'schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/…;
>   data contract. The deserializer has no
>   knowledge of any type that maps to
>   this contract. Add the type
>   corresponding to
>   'ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringClassValuesNSpYOWsW'
>   to the list of known types - for
>   example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding it to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.'

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting a serialization exception, or simply empty properties? More info is required.

Comment: everything builds and updates fine. when I am running and it actually tries to serialize the object to send to the client, it is getting a serialization exception.

Comment: the exception is this : Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value' contains data of the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringClassValuesNSpYOWsW' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringClassValuesNSpYOWsW' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.

Comment: One thing I am unsure of, it creates the information in the xsd this way with the name having garbled letters on the ende of it, not sure if there is a problem with that but maybe thats the source of my frustrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to work out where this is failing, I've set up a simple WCF service that returns a very basic nested `Dictionary` which works perfectly well with a number of items added to it.

```
    [OperationContract]
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> GetDictionary();
```

Based on this, I am assuming it's a problem with your objects (& *perhaps* the fact that they are in `Dictionary` collections).  I suggest you do some tests to narrow down your problem.

Is your class serializable - can you deserialize a single instance of your type? (e.g. write an operation to return an object like `MyClass GetOneInstance();`). Are you able to return a simple `Dictionary` of your class?

There are a handful of naming clashes that WCF can throw up at you - if your classes have the same name as your service or your operation, for example an operation `GetSomething` and an object called `GetSomethingRequest` or `GetSomethingResponse` will not work well together - essentially due to the request and response being put into automatically-named SOAP envelopes. If your classes are named using some reserved word you could try renaming them.

The exception suggests that you add the `KnownType` attribute. This is usually applicable when you are returning a base type which could be an instance of an inheriting type - is this the case? Do your objects involve inheritance, and are you returning base types which could be instances of inheriting types? (e.g. `A:B` and your operation returns a `B`, but it may be an `A`)

Comment: I stepped through it as you suggested, definitely helped me narrow down the problem.

Comment: with the known type if you return a dictionary<string,object> and in that dictionary you are going to have an instance of A or B, does the KnowTypeAttribute have to be for `KnownType(typeof(A))` or `KnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string,A>))`?

Comment: @tam I believe you only need to specify the known types which need disambiguation (i.e. A or B). It's always going to be a Dictionary, so the Dictionary type would already be included in the contract. It's just the A & B that are not concrete.